# Как вывести на монитор пошаговое умножение целых чисел?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Завдання 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
{
    document.write("<br>"+"Покрокове додавання парних чисел:");
    for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
      sum = sum += i++;
      document.write(" " + sum);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пробовал так, но не получилось

Comment: Чем умножение отличается от сложения?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Завдання 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let sum = 0;
    document.write("<br>" + "Покрокове додавання парних чисел:");
    for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
      sum += i++;
      document.write(" " + sum);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы оно считало все числа, а не через одно?

Comment: @Давид Выводятся квадраты *всех* чисел - от одного до двадцати.